# I want to delete a null column from a 2d array in android?

Tags: android

i have problem in data binding in expandable list view. here i use

```
ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> list = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
```

ExpandListGroup for data binding. but in sum 2d array there is null value.Data is coming dynamically .

eg:

```
String [] [] array1 = [[one,two,three,null],[seven,six,null]] ;
```

I want to remove the null column from this two dimensional array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a intermediate arraylist and result array and follows the below steps.

1. First copy the source array(containing null) into arraylist.
2. Then remove null from arraylist
3. Then create new array and copy data from arraylist to array.

   private void remove_nulls()
        {

   ```
        String [] [] array1 = {{"one","two","three",null},{"seven","six",null}} ;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> contact = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
        {
            ArrayList<String> con = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int j=0;j<array1[i].length;j++)
            {

                if(array1[i][j]!=null)
                con.add(array1[i][j]);
            }
            if(con.size()>0)
                contact.add(con);
        }
        String [] [] array2 = new String[array1.length][];
        for(int i=0;i<contact.size();i++)
        {
            array2[i]=new String[contact.get(i).size()];
            for(int j=0;j<contact.get(i).size();j++)
            {
                array2[i][j]=contact.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some trick to the question...

```
String[][] array1 = {{"one", "two", "three", null}, {"seven", "six", null}};

List<String[]> newList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    List<String> currentLine = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < array1[i].length; ++j) {
        if (array1[i][j] != null) {
            currentLine.add(array1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //create the array in place
    newList.add(currentLine.toArray(new String[currentLine.size()]));
}
//no need to use an intermediate array
String[][] array2 = newList.toArray(new String [newList.size()][]);

//And a test for array2
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array2[i].length; ++j) {
        System.out.print(array2[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println("Compared to...");
//Compared to the original array1
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array1[i].length; ++j) {
        System.out.print(array1[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```